# Get POINT CLOUD through 360 Degree Rotation and Image Processing

Tags: algorithm, math, image-processing, 3d, scanning

My Question is as below in two parts……

**QUESTION (IN SHORT):**

•   To generate [point cloud](https://picasaweb.google.com/paryanh.job/POINTCLOUD?authkey=Gv1sRgCNbwzqi34bTg4gE#5609834316945961266) of real-world object….

•   Through 360 degree rotation of it….on rotating table

•   Getting 360 images… one image at each degree (1° to 360°).

•   I know how to process image and getting pixel value of it.

•   See one sample image below…you can see image is black and white...because I have to deal with the objects which are much shiny (glittery)…and it is DIAMOND. So I have setting up background so that shiny object (diamond) converted in to B/W object. And so I can easily scan outer edge of object (e.g. Diamond).

•   And one thing to consider is I don’t using any laser… I just using one rotating table and one camera for taking image…you can see one sample project over [here](http://www.volunteerlabrat.com/default.html?goto=scanner.html)… but there MATLAB hides all the things…because that guy using MATLAB’s in Built functionality.

•   **Actually I am looking for Math routine or Algorithm or any Technique which helping me out to how getting point cloud…….using the way I have mentioned……..**

**MORE ELABORATION:**

I need to have point-cloud of real-world object.  So, I can display it in Computer Screen.

For that I am using one rotating table. I will put my object on it and I will rotate table a complete 360° degree rotation and I will take 360 images…one image at each degree (1° to 360°).

Camera which is used for taking image is well calibrated. I have given one sample image as below. I also know how to scan image and getting pixel value of it.

Also take in consideration that my images are [Silhouette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette) type…means just black and white... No color images.

But my problem is or where I am trapped down is in...

Getting Points cloud of object…….from the data which I have getting through processing of image.

One same kind of project I found over [here](http://www.volunteerlabrat.com/default.html?goto=scanner.html)……..
But it just using built in MATLAB functions…I am using Microsoft Visual C#.Net so I have to build the entire algorithm myself….because MATLAB hides all the things which I want to know….

Is there any master…….who know this entire thing well and getting me out of trap...!!!!
[image]

Thanks…..

Comment: What technique is it you want to use? You're mentioning previous work using structured light, but show an image with a red contour. Is this red contour something you're already able to generate yourself?

Comment: no..no....  That red line is drawn by me....that is scan line....outer line of object...i will take pixel value(x,y value) along that red line...

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience of this but If I wanted to do something like this I would have tried this:

1. Use a single color light source
2. if Possible create a lightsource which falls on a thin verticle slice of the object.
3. have 360 B/W Images, those Images will be images of a verticle line having variyng intensity. If you use matlab your matrix will have a/few column with sime values.
4. now asume a verticle line(your Axis of rotation).
   5 plot or convert  (imageno, rownoOfMatrix, ValueInPopulatedColumnInSameRow)... [Assuming numbering Image from 0 to 360]
5. under ideal conditions A lame way To get X and Y use K1 * cos imgNo * ValInCol and K1 * sin imgNo * ValInCol, and Z will be some K2 * rowNum.. K1 and K2 can be caliberated knowing actual size of object.

I mean Something like this:
http://fab.cba.mit.edu/content/processes/structured_light/

but instead of using structured light using a single verticle light

http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~samuelp/del_project.html This link might help in triangulation...

Comment: Pritesh, I have edited my answer after your comment and I actually can't see the Image which you have posted... If you can show any Image I can say more... you mentioned your Image is Silhouette I couldn't imagine hoe good Silhouette something shiny can make..

Comment: you can see one video over here [http://www.youtube.com/user/PriteshAryan?feature=mhee] ......that will explain what i exactly need is......by the way...though i have displayed 3D Object in Computer screen using just single camera....in that video...but it is not much accurate...so i am looking for the standard way....